# Is it true that $\operatorname{inj.dim}_R R= \operatorname{inj.dim}_R \widehat{R}?$ Is there a one-sided inequality?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

$(R,m)$ is a local ring. 
Is it true that $\operatorname{inj.dim}_R  R= \operatorname{inj.dim}_R \widehat{R}?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\operatorname{inj.dim}_R  R\le \operatorname{inj.dim}_R \widehat{R}$ since $R \subset \widehat{R}$ is pure.

Comment: This should be explained more deeply (if true, of course): in general, if $M$ is a submodule of $N$, it's false that $\operatorname{inj.dim}_R M\le\operatorname{inj.dim}_R N$ (think when $N$ is the injective envelope of $M$).